# Javascript Object's variables undefined

Tags: javascript

I have created a javascript object as part of a visualization I am working on, and am funning into an issue with the object's instance variables. The relevant code is below:

```
function bubble() {
        //don't use these functions elsewhere--only modify them to change behavior
            this.color;
            this.bubbleCircles = chart.selectAll("circle");
                //.data(array,function(d){return d['date'];});

            this.bubbleCirclesEnter = function(selection){
                selection.enter().append("circle")
                    .style('stroke',this.color)
                    .style('fill',this.color)
                    .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return x(i); })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d["measure"]) - 1.5*bubbleRadius; })
                    .attr("r", 0);
                    console.log(this.color);
                };

            this.bubbleCirclesEnterTransition = function(selection){
                return selection.transition()
                    .duration(400)
                    .delay(function(d,i){return i*segmentDuration;})
                    .ease('elastic')
                    .attr("r", bubbleRadius);
                };

            this.bubbleText = chart.selectAll('.label');
                //.data(array,function(d){return d['date'];});

            this.bubbleTextEnter = function(selection){
                selection
                    .enter().append("text")
                    .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) - (13.0/16)*bubbleNumberSize; })
                    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return y(d['measure']) - 1.5*bubbleRadius + bubbleNumberSize*(5.0/16); })
                    .style("font-size", bubbleNumberSize.toString() + "px")
                    .style('fill',white)
                    .style('fill-opacity',1.0)
                    .style('stroke',white)
                    .style('stroke-opacity',1.0)
                    .text(function (d, i) { return d['measure'].toFixed(2); });
            };
        //actually use these ones

            this.enter = function() {
                this.bubbleCircles = this.bubbleCircles.call(this.bubbleCirclesEnter);
                this.bubbleText = this.bubbleText.call(this.bubbleTextEnter);
            };

            this.enterTransition = function() {
                this.bubbleCircles.call(this.bubbleCirclesEnterTransition);
            };

            this.draw = function() {
                this.enter();
                this.enterTransition();
            };

            this.setData = function(dataSet) {
                this.bubbleCircles = this.bubbleCircles.data(dataSet,function(d){ return d['date']; });
                this.bubbleText = this.bubbleText.data(dataSet,function(d){ return d['date']; });
            };

            this.setColor = function(bubblesColor) {
                this.color = bubblesColor;
            };
        };
```

The problem is with the this.color variable. It gets set when the 'setColor' method is called, but, later, when bubbleCirclesEnter is called (via this.draw and this.enter), a console.log of the variable shows that it is undefined.

If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What is `this.bubbleCircles.call`? What library are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` changes scope throughout the object.  When you enter any of your functions, the scope of `this` moves from a global scope to the local scope of the function.  Generally what I've seen done is to set a new variable equal to this as another member. This article explains in better words than I can: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

```
function bubble() {
    //don't use these functions elsewhere--only modify them to change behavior
        this.color;
        this.bubbleCircles = chart.selectAll("circle");
        var me = this;
```

.
.
.

```
this.bubbleCirclesEnter = function(selection){
            selection.enter().append("circle")
                .style('stroke',me.color)
                .style('fill',me.color)
                .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return x(i); })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d["measure"]) - 1.5*bubbleRadius; })
                .attr("r", 0);
                console.log(me.color);
            };
```

Comment: "*the scope of `this` becomes the function*" is a littlebit inaccurate. Please clarify or link to some docs explaining it.

Comment: Seemed perfectly clear to me! I had a feeling it was some sort of scope issue like that -- thanks for the help!

Comment: Well actually the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has nothing to do with the *scope* of a function. It's the calling *context* that is relevant for `this`. If you had used the variable scope (`var color` instead of a property) the problem would've gone away :)

Comment: I disagree with that.  The OP obviously wants to access the color property from outside the object, so using a variable instead of a property wouldn't be an option.

Comment: We don't see the code that makes use of the `bubble`s so we can't be sure about that… He also has an explicit setter already which might indicate the use of a strict encapsulation :-)

Comment: Ok, I missed the setter even after scanning for it.  We should still try not to eliminate any of the OP's functionality (getter) in a solution.  If the OP added a getter, then I think the variable would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score -1):

Just a idea:

Try to declare the color variable in your function:

```
function bubble() {
        //don't use these functions elsewhere--only modify them to change behavior
            var color = "";
   //rest of the code
```

Comment: Since you didn't declare your variable, it's undefined. You could use strict mode to avoid that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: Then no. OP does not have a variable, he has a property.